# How to align text in buttons in CSS

Tags: css

I'm making a website and I want to align text in my buttons but can't get it to work.

I've tried to use line-height and box-sizing, changing the display, changing the text-align etc

```css
      .button {
            background-color: rgb(71, 37, 85);
            border: solid;
            color: rgb(199, 173, 211);
            padding: 20px 95px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 50px;
            max-height: 30px;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }
```

The text isn't centered and it's like beyond the button
[Here's a codepen for you to try it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEOBjL)

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help you.

Comment: can i get a code sandbox or something?

Comment: Here's the codepen @AjayVarghese [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEOBjL)

Comment: before setting hudge padding and smaller max-width/max-height , you should read this : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html padding:20px 95px makes a box of 40px x 190px if it is empty .so max-width:50px and max-height:30px seems  a big joke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `max-width: 50px;` and `max-height: 30px;` which makes the button very small (if you take the padding off).

So if you remove these, and then set the padding to something smaller like `padding: 10px 20px;`, then I think you'll find a nicer button option.

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(71, 37, 85);
  border: solid;
  color: rgb(199, 173, 211);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(155, 41, 139);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.fr" class="button">Here's some text<a>
```

**Edit:** You can also change the `font-size` if you are looking for something smaller. Like this:

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(71, 37, 85);
  border: solid;
  color: rgb(199, 173, 211);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  margin: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(155, 41, 139);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.fr" class="button">Here's some text<a>
```

Or if you are looking for a set size of button throughout your website, then you can put (for example) `width: 150px` and `text-align: center`.

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(71, 37, 85);
  border: solid;
  color: rgb(199, 173, 211);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(155, 41, 139);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.fr" class="button">Here's some text<a>

<a href="https://google.fr" class="button">Go here<a>

<a href="https://google.fr" class="button">Here is a link<a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring because of your **padding** and **max-height/max-width**.

Try removing your padding or removing your max-width and max-height.

Answer (score 0):

It's breaking because of the padding. Try below code. I have commented some lines which were the cause of the issue.

```
.button {
        background-color: rgb(71, 37, 85);
        border: solid;
        color: rgb(199, 173, 211);
       /* padding: 20px 95px; */
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
       /* max-width: 50px; */
        max-width: 150px;
        max-height: 30px;
        border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your max-height and max-width are limiting the height and width of your button. Remove max-width and max-height.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you have to consider Max width/height, padding & display. Since you have already mentioned display:inline and max-width/max-height. Its messing up. here is the fix

```css
 .button {
            background-color: rgb(71, 37, 85);
            border: solid;
            color: rgb(199, 173, 211);
            padding: 13px 68px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }
```

```html
<button class="button"> BUTTON </button>
```

Comment: yeah but it makes the buttons kinda too big :/

Comment: what is the button size you are expecting ?

Comment: Check, just updated to match your button dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of how you can change you CSS. You are specifying some very large left and right padding values - it would be better to set a smaller padding value (i.e. 20px) and then center align your text in an element that has a minimum width.

The code below has four buttons

Your original styling is the first button. The second and third buttons show some improved styling which centers the text and ensures the button is a set width. The third button shows an issue with a set width button and longer text - i.e. that the overflow is not hidden.

The final button shows the improved CSS to center your text, and also condenses the overflow text using the ellipses.

I would recommend deleting the following lines:

```
padding: 20px 95px;
max-width: 50px;
```

And adding the following:

```
padding: 20px;
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 200px;
text-align: center;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

---

## Demo

```css
.button_new {
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button_condense {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button_old {
  padding: 20px 95px;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(71, 37, 85);
  border: solid;
  color: rgb(199, 173, 211);
  max-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: start;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<a href=https://google.fr class="button button_old">Here's some text<a>
<a href=https://google.fr class="button button_new">Here's some text<a>
<a href=https://google.fr class="button button_new">Here's some text which is longer<a>
<a href=https://google.fr class="button button_new button_condense">Here's some text which is longer<a>
```